# 'null coalescing' TS-friendly function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to get a 'null coalescing function' working in TS.  Basically `get(obj, 'key1', 'key2', 'key3')`

Here's what I have:

```
const X = {
    a: 42,
    b: 'bar',
    c: {
        d: 'foo'
    }
}

function get<T, K extends keyof T>(item: T, key: K, ...more: string[]): T[K] | null {
  if (key in item) {
    const out = item[key];
    if (more.length) {
      return get(out, more[0], ...more.slice(1));
    } else {
      return out;
    }
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

const foo = get(X, 'c', 'd');
```

This works at the top level, e.g. `get(X, 'c')`, but breaks down on the recursion for some reason I can't figure out.  Whatever I try I get various TS errors that all more or less say I can't cast a string to `keyof T[K]`, even though that's exactly what I'm doing the first time I call it!

help!

[edit] So this works, but is ugly AF!  somebody help meeeeee

```
function get<T, K extends keyof T>(item: T, key: K): T[K] | null;
function get<T, K extends keyof T, L extends keyof T[K]>(item: T, key1: K, key2: L): T[K][L] | null;
function get<T, K extends keyof T, L extends keyof T[K], M extends keyof T[K][L]>(item: T, key1: K, key2: L, key3: M): T[K][L][M] | null;
function get(obj, key, ...moreKeys) {
  ...
```

Comment: TS, ugly AF should be the new TS motto. There is no better way to write this at the moment since each key depends on the previous...

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir -- Why am I unable to make a recursive version of this?  TS seems to support recursion but it falls apart here

Comment: I mean for the signature. Yes in general TS supports recursive types, but this particular case just can't be modeled in TS, as far as I know, and as far as I have seen, this questions and similar have been asked several times before, I have not seen a better answer than the one with multiple overloads one for each depth you want to support

Comment: meh!  well thanks for the confirmation anyway!

Comment: It seems like you have two conflicting ideas here. Ignoring the recursive bit for a minute, your function checks if `key` exists on `item`. But at the same time, you are telling TS that `key` must be on `item` by using `K extends keyof T`. Unless you're doing unsafe casts, the check `if (key in item)` should never be false correct?

Comment: @JustinHoward -- Correct, nice catch!  I'm actually converting some of our utility code to TS which is where that's coming from, but in a pure TS world it's unneeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently in TypeScript it's not possible to express deep type paths like you're trying to achieve. There is a GitHub issue [discussing possible workarounds](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12290) similar to your own. There is also a proposal [suggesting the "pathof" keyword](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20423) to solve this exact issue.

In the meantime, it seems like you'll need to define your types exhaustively to X levels like you've done in your edit.